# Salesforce object logic question

Tags: object, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

We have a custom object in Salesforce called "domain" which reflects each website we have built and manage. Our domains use a in house system we sell which has modules which have these attributes: A name, a default price, an expiry date and the actual price the client is paying. We need a way to link these modules to a domain so we could choose that "domain.com" uses - for example - Modules 1,2 and 4.

From this choice of modules we would want to automatically generate a total price that that client is paying based on these chosen modules, the formula would be a core price plus the individual price for each of the chosen modules.  We would need to be able to create a view and reports based on this query so we could - for example - return all domains which are using Module 1.

Ideally these modules would be standardised across the system and to a certain extent it would work like a price book does for opportunities. I am quite familiar with general object management in Salesforce but havent really looked much into visualforce/apex. It is also important that any solution only makes use of functionality in Professional Edition.

I can't seem to quite get my head round the best way to approach this, any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution to this. It involved the creation of "[Junction Objects](http://blogs.salesforce.com/analytics/2007/10/hiding-or-polit.html)" which allow many-to-many relationships between objects. I created a junction object between domain and module to act as a pivot between them.